# Pass Params For Overflow On strcmp()

Tags: c#, c

So I have written a small app to trigger an [academic buffer overflow attack](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~tschwarz/coen152_05/Lectures/BufferOverflow.html) to compromise the `strcmp()` of a C executable that takes input via. command line arguments. My C# code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string cPath = @"C:\Debug";
    var strCmdText = "pass";
    string filename = Path.Combine(cPath, "Buffer.exe");
    var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename, strCmdText);
}
```

So, if I am not incorrect I will need to pass a sufficiently long string with hex, garbage or unprintable characters like this `perl` script can do ([source](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~tschwarz/coen152_05/Lectures/BufferOverflow.html)):

[image: http://www.cse.scu.edu/~tschwarz/coen152_05/Lectures/BufferOverflow.html]

How can I achieve this using C#?

For reference, my C side of code looks viz.

```
char pass[256];
if (strcmp(pass, "passme") == 0)
{
    crack = TRUE;
}
if (crack == TRUE)
{
    printf("You did it!");
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I highly doubt that you will be able to overwrite function return address by passing an arbitrary large input to [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

Why? Because to **overwrite something** you have to, well, **write something**. And `strcmp` shouldn't write anything at any address (barring its own stack space), as it

> Compares the C string str1 to the C string str2.

Well, there may be some nonstandard implementation, but that is nigh impossible to find such things in any widespread stdlib implementation.

Arbitrary large (not terminated with `'\0'` string can lead to [access violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), though any sensible `strcmp` implementation will ["short circuit"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)(won't wait till the end) on the first not-equal character. Also, you can pass only 2<sup>15</sup> - 256 - 4 characters to your "Buffer.exe" as an argument line (on Win32).

So, you probably meant [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/). In case if you have some problems (like turned on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection features in Buffer.exe) with reproducing the overflow with that function, then feel free to ask another question.

Comment: I will ask a different question.